# How to fix for the GDAL clipper tool in QGIS? 

Tags: qgis, gdal, clip

I would like to clip a DEM with an admin boundary using qgis, in order to calculate a measure of variation.  However, when I use the Raster clipper tools and select mask, I get the error message: "An error has occured while executing Python code: ...".

It seems this has been noticed by others: see http://osgeo-org.1803224.n2.nabble.com/Re-qgis2google-and-clipper-plugins-td6604408.html

Does this imply that the tool is unavailable for use with Wroclaw 1.7.3?

All I am looking for is a measure of variation based on an admin boundary, and was planning to use the ruggedness index.

Is there a fix for the clipper tool I am unaware of, or any other simple way to calculate a measure of topological variation?  It doesn't have to be ruggedness.

Thanks!

Comment: what version of gdal tools (see in the "raster" menu) are you using?

Comment: Giovanni, I am using GDAL v. 1.8.1

Answer (score 2):

It's due to a [python bug](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/pipermail/pyqt/2011-February/029218.html), fixed in python v2.5.3 and v2.6.1. 
Here's the [ticket](http://hub.qgis.org/issues/4676) on QGis trac about that issue.

You can upgrade python (OSGeo4W is moving to python2.7) or remove the affected line (and also few lines below it) or even... use Linux.

Comment: Giuseppe, I installed 2.7.2 for OSX 1.7, but the clipper is still not working for me.  Do I need to update any pathways or anything?

Comment: @user5533 I think QGis is still using the old python. Please, run Qgis and from menu Plugins click on Python Console. In the console execute `import sys; sys.version` and report here.

Comment: '2.7.1 (r271:86832, Jun 16 2011, 16:59:05) \n[GCC 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2335.15.00)]'

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer to your question, but a possible workaround: You could convert your vector mask to a raster, and do your processing using all raster data.

I would also suggest trying to run the command directly in GDAL rather than via QGIS. Sometimes I've had luck doing that!